# how to unselect a previously set selection on input radio in angular typescript

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a json like below in my component:

```
radioData:[]=
[
    {
        id: 1,
        description: 'entry 1'
        ,isSelected: true
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        description: 'entry 2'
         ,isSelected: false
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        description: 'entry 3'
         ,isSelected: false
    },
    {
        id: 4,
        description: 'entry 4'
    }

]
```

I am trying to display radio buttons and preselect one based on `isSelected` field to TRUE.Only one entry will have `isSelected` set to TRUE. And i render them in html like below:

```
<table *ngIf="radioData">  
    <tr *ngFor="let iRadio of radioData; let i = index">
      <td>
          <input type="radio" name="radioGroup" [value]="true"  [(ngModel)] ="iRadio.isSelected" [checked] ="iRadio.isSelected" > 
          <label>{{iRadio.description}} </label> 
      <td>
    </tr>
</table>

<button (click)="viewUpdates()">View</button>
```

When the selection change from one radio button to another radio button , the newly selected radio button's field `isSelected` changes to TRUE but the previously selected radio button's field `isSelected` is still set to TRUE. But in UI i can see the newly selected radio button is selected

How do i unselect a previously set selection on radio in this scenario ?

Comment: A radio group is severals input type radio each one with a **different** value (if we are using ngModel with the same [(ngModel)]="variable"). The input type radio selected is the radio wich the value is equal to the variable. You has a series of radio with the same value: "true". It has no sense

Comment: @Eliseo It's the same result , even if i make value attribute to be unique : <input type="radio" name="radioGroup"   [checked]="iRadio.isSelected" [value]="iRadio.id" (change)="iRadio.isSelected=$event.target.checked">

Comment: @krrisha, first. In angular NOT use [checked], just give value to the variable (in your case iRadio.isSelect. second you have a **type="radio"**, you can NOT give the same value to a radio group. Do you want to use type="checkbox" ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add some property in your component to track the currently selected item.

`public selectedIndex = 0`

And set the item with `selectedIndex` to false, before updating `selectedIndex` when new option is selected (watch out for `ngModelChange` event).

```
<table *ngIf="radioData">  
    <tr *ngFor="let iRadio of radioData; let i = index">
      <td>
          <input type="radio" name="radioGroup" [value]="true"  
            (ngModelChange) = "radioData[currentIndex].isSelected = false; currentIndex=i"  
             [checked] = "iRadio.isSelected" [(ngModel)] = "iRadio.isSelected" > 
           <label>{{iRadio.description}} </label> 
          <td> 
        </tr>
    </table>
```

[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-radio-amit?file=src/app/app.component.html)

Comment: Thanks, Amit. I was trying to see if this is possible to do within HTML to avoid selectedIndex  property. Your demo works though.

Comment: The problem is to track previously selected index. One extra variable needed to do the work. Rest all is done in template.

Comment: You could have at least mentioned that in your question clearly. I cannot see it anywhere. And doing all in html does not make sense at all. Take advantage of Angular and Typescript.